# How to prove the lack of implicit order in a database?

Tags: order-by, data-integrity

Recently I was explaining to colleagues the importance of having a column by which to sort data in a database table if it is necessary to do so, for example for chronologically-ordered data. This proved somewhat difficult because they could simply re-run their query seemingly endlessly and it would always return the same set of rows in the same order.

I have noticed this before and all I could really do is insist that they trust me and not simply assume that a database table will behave like a traditional CSV or Excel file.

For example, executing the (PostgreSQL) query

```
create table mytable (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    data TEXT
);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
    (0, 'a'),
    (1, 'b'),
    (2, 'c'),
    (3, 'd'),
    (4, 'e'),
    (5, 'f'),
    (6, 'g'),
    (7, 'h'),
    (8, 'i'),
    (9, 'j');
```

will create a table with a clear conceptual order. Selecting that same data in the simplest way would be:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Always gives me the following results:

```
 id | data 
----+------
  0 | a
  1 | b
  2 | c
  3 | d
  4 | e
  5 | f
  6 | g
  7 | h
  8 | i
  9 | j
(10 rows)
```

I can do this over and over again and it will always return to me the same data in the same order. However I know that this implicit order can be broken, I have seen it before, particularly in large datasets, where some random value will get apparently thrown up into the "wrong" place when selected. But it has occurred to me that I don't know how this happens or how to reproduce it. I find it difficult to get results on Google because the search query tends to just return general help on sorting result sets.

So, my questions are essentially these:

1. How can I demonstrably and concretely prove that the return order of rows from a query without an `ORDER BY` statement is not reliable, preferably by causing and showing a breakdown of the implicit order **even when the table in question is not updated or edited**?
2. Does it make any difference at all if the data is only inserted once en masse and then never updated again?

I would prefer a postgres-based answer since that is the one I am most familiar with but I'm more interested in the theory itself.

Answer (score 33):

I see three ways to try to convince them:

1. Let them try the same query but with bigger table (more number of rows) or when the table is being updated between executions. Or new rows are inserted and some old ones are deleted. Or an index is added or removed between executions. Or the table is vacuumed (in Postgres). Or indexes are rebuilt (in SQL Server). Or the table is changed from clustered to a heap. Or the database service is restarted.
2. You can suggest that they prove that different executions will return the same order. Can they prove it? Can they provide a series of tests that proves that **any query** will give the result in the same order, no matter how many times it is executed?
3. Provide the documentation of various DBMS in that matter. For example:

**[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-order.html)**:

> **Sorting Rows**
>
> After a query has produced an output table (after the select list has been processed) it can optionally be sorted. **If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order.** The actual order in that case **will depend** on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, **but it must not be relied on.** A particular output ordering can only be guaranteed if the sort step is explicitly chosen.

**[SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**:

> **`SELECT` - `ORDER BY` Clause (Transact-SQL)**
>
> Sorts data returned by a query in SQL Server. Use this clause to:
>
> Order the result set of a query by the specified column list and, optionally, limit the rows returned to a specified range. **The order in which rows are returned in a result set are not guaranteed unless an `ORDER BY` clause is specified.**

**[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)**:

> *`order_by_clause`*
>
> Use the `ORDER BY` clause to order rows returned by the statement. **Without an order_by_clause, no guarantee exists that the same query executed more than once will retrieve rows in the same order.**

Answer (score 22):

This is the black swan story all over again. If you haven't seen one yet it doesn't mean they don't exist. Hopefully in your case it won't lead to another world wide financial crisis, simply to a few unhappy customers.

Postgres [documentation says this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-select.html) explicitly:

> If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce.

"The system" in this case comprises the postgres daemon itself (including implementation of its data access methods and the query optimizer), the underlying operating system, logical and physical layout of the database storage, possibly even CPU caches. Since you as the database user have no control over that stack you should not rely on it continuing to behave forever the way it behaves this very minute.

Your colleagues are committing the [hasty generalization fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization#Hasty_generalization). To disprove their point it is sufficient to show that their assumption is wrong only once, e.g. by [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5aea2da2891376b02ab0cabc638a984f).

Answer (score 12):

Consider the following example, where we have three related tables.  Orders, Users, and OrderDetails.  OrderDetails is linked with foreign keys to the Orders table and the Users Table.  This is essentially a very typical setup for relational databases; arguably the entire purpose of a *relational* DBMS.

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.OrderDetails', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.OrderDetails;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Orders', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Orders;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Users', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Users;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders
(
    OrderID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT OrderTestPK
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , SomeOrderData varchar(1000)
        CONSTRAINT Orders_somedata_df
        DEFAULT (CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1000))
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Users
(
    UserID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT UsersPK
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , SomeUserData varchar(1000)
        CONSTRAINT Users_somedata_df
        DEFAULT (CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1000))
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderDetails
(
    OrderDetailsID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT OrderDetailsTestPK
        PRIMARY KEY
        CLUSTERED
    , OrderID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT OrderDetailsOrderID
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.Orders(OrderID)
    , UserID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT OrderDetailsUserID
        FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.Users(UserID)
    , SomeOrderDetailsData varchar(1000)
        CONSTRAINT OrderDetails_somedata_df
        DEFAULT (CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1000))
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (OrderID)
SELECT TOP(100) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM sys.syscolumns sc;

INSERT INTO dbo.Users (UserID)
SELECT TOP(100) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM sys.syscolumns sc;

INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails (OrderDetailsID, OrderID, UserID)
SELECT TOP(10000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    , o.OrderID
    , u.UserID
FROM sys.syscolumns sc
    CROSS JOIN dbo.Orders o
    CROSS JOIN dbo.Users u
ORDER BY NEWID();

CREATE INDEX OrderDetailsOrderID ON dbo.OrderDetails(OrderID);
CREATE INDEX OrderDetailsUserID ON dbo.OrderDetails(UserID);
```

Here, we're querying the OrderDetails table where the UserID is 15:

```
SELECT od.OrderDetailsID
    , o.OrderID
    , u.UserID
FROM dbo.OrderDetails od
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON u.UserID = od.UserID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
WHERE u.UserID = 15
```

The output from the query looks like:

```
╔════════════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ OrderDetailsID ║ OrderID ║ UserID ║
╠════════════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║        2200115 ║       2 ║     15 ║
║         630215 ║       3 ║     15 ║
║        1990215 ║       3 ║     15 ║
║        4960215 ║       3 ║     15 ║
║         100715 ║       8 ║     15 ║
║        3930815 ║       9 ║     15 ║
║        6310815 ║       9 ║     15 ║
║        4441015 ║      11 ║     15 ║
║        2171315 ║      14 ║     15 ║
║        3431415 ║      15 ║     15 ║
║        4571415 ║      15 ║     15 ║
║        6421515 ║      16 ║     15 ║
║        2271715 ║      18 ║     15 ║
║        2601715 ║      18 ║     15 ║
║        3521715 ║      18 ║     15 ║
║         221815 ║      19 ║     15 ║
║        3381915 ║      20 ║     15 ║
║        4471915 ║      20 ║     15 ║
╚════════════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

As you can see, the order of rows output does not match the order of rows in the OrderDetails table.

Adding an explicit `ORDER BY` ensures rows will be returned to the client in the desired order:

```
SELECT od.OrderDetailsID
    , o.OrderID
    , u.UserID
FROM dbo.OrderDetails od
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON u.UserID = od.UserID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
WHERE u.UserID = 15
ORDER BY od.OrderDetailsID;
```

```
╔════════════════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ OrderDetailsID ║ OrderID ║ UserID ║
╠════════════════╬═════════╬════════╣
║           3915 ║      40 ║     15 ║
║         100715 ║       8 ║     15 ║
║         221815 ║      19 ║     15 ║
║         299915 ║     100 ║     15 ║
║         368215 ║      83 ║     15 ║
║         603815 ║      39 ║     15 ║
║         630215 ║       3 ║     15 ║
║         728515 ║      86 ║     15 ║
║         972215 ║      23 ║     15 ║
║         992015 ║      21 ║     15 ║
║        1017115 ║      72 ║     15 ║
║        1113815 ║      39 ║     15 ║
╚════════════════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

If order of rows is imperative, and your engineers know that order is imperative, they should only ever *want* to use an `ORDER BY` statement, since it might cost them their designation if there was a failure related to incorrect order.

A second, perhaps more instructive example, using the `OrderDetails` table from above, where we're *not* joining any other tables, but have a simple requirement to find rows matching both the OrderID and the UserID, we see the problem.

We'll create an index to support the query, as you would likely do in real life if performance is in any way important (when isn't it?).

```
CREATE INDEX OrderDetailsOrderIDUserID ON dbo.OrderDetails(OrderID, UserID);
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT od.OrderDetailsID
FROM dbo.OrderDetails od
WHERE od.OrderID = 15
    AND (od.UserID = 21 OR od.UserID = 22)
```

And the results:

```
╔════════════════╗
║ OrderDetailsID ║
╠════════════════╣
║          21421 ║
║        5061421 ║
║        7091421 ║
║         691422 ║
║        3471422 ║
║        7241422 ║
╚════════════════╝
```

Adding an `ORDER BY` clause will most definitely ensure we get the correct sort here, too.

These mock-ups are just simple examples where rows are not guaranteed to be "in order" without an explicit `ORDER BY` statement.  There are many more example like this, and since DBMS engine code changes quite frequently, the specific behavior may change over time.

Answer (score 11):

As a practical example, in Postgres, the order currently changes when you update a row:

```
% SELECT * FROM mytable;
 id | data 
----+------
  0 | a
  1 | b
  2 | c
  3 | d
  4 | e
  5 | f
  6 | g
  7 | h
  8 | i
  9 | j
(10 rows)

% UPDATE mytable SET data = 'ff' WHERE id = 5;
UPDATE 1
% SELECT * FROM mytable;
 id | data 
----+------
  0 | a
  1 | b
  2 | c
  3 | d
  4 | e
  6 | g
  7 | h
  8 | i
  9 | j
  5 | ff
(10 rows)
```

I don't think the rules of this existing implicit ordering is documented anywhere, is definitely subject to change without notice, and is definitely not portable behavior across DB engines.

Answer (score 4):

not exactly a demo, but too long for a comment.

On large tables some databases will do interleaved parallel scans:

If two queries want to scan the same table, and arrive at almost the same time, the first might be part way through the table when the second starts.

The second query could receive records starting from the middle of the table (as the first query is completing) and then receive the records from the start of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Create a clustered index that has the "wrong" order. For example, cluster on `ID DESC`. This will often output the reverse order (although this is not guaranteed either).