# mismatch between server schema content and exported sql rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysqldump

I am using `MySQL` 5.6.44 within `phpMyAdmin` on Go Daddy shared hosting and experimenting with some duplicate table data.

I am trying to figure out, when I export my table from `phpMyAdmin` the exported `sql` file structure when opened does not match the schema seen in the admin panel. By that I mean the row sequence in the `sql` file are jumbled up.

I don't have any foreign key constraints set up or any other operations on the table.

Any steering and knowledge as to why this might be the case would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you want an order on your data, you need to use an `order by` clause. An SQL database makes no guarantees about the order the data is stored or returned.

Comment: appreciate the notes but what resolved the issue as mentioned was changing the engine as I mentioned from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Comment: Those rows are sorted as strings, not numbers.  What process generated them?

Answer (score -1):

The issue disappeared when I changed the engine from MyISAM to InnoDB. I understand that InnoDB has row locking.

Comment: What does the row order have to do with  locking?

Comment: My solution works, appreciate the down vote.

Comment: You might find [this Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228131/) useful.

Comment: I suspect it was _coincidence_ that led to it "working".