# PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON forces a specific order

Tags: postgresql, distinct

Why `DISTINCT ON` is sorting the rows? E.g. the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a) a
FROM (
  VALUES (2), (3), (1)
) x(a);
```

will have the result

```
1
2
3
```

while without `DISTINCT ON`

```
SELECT a
FROM (
  VALUES (2), (3), (1)
) x(a);
```

I'll get the correct order

```
2
3
1
```

How can I preserve the natural order of defined values?  By "natural order" I mean "the order in which the values were defined". I understand that DBMS may change the order if I don't specify it explicitly with an `ORDER BY`, but I was not expecting that `DISTINCT ON` my interfere in this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove the lack of implicit order in a database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228131/how-to-prove-the-lack-of-implicit-order-in-a-database)

Comment: There is no natural order. Without an order by clause the DBMS is free to return rows in whatever order it finds best. The optimizer can use this freedom to create more efficient plans than otherwise would be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why DISTINCT ON is sorting the rows?

Distinct removes "duplicate" rows from the result set.  That's a *whole* lot easier to do if the items being compared arrive neatly sorted into order.

Check the Explain Plan for this query - it will probably contain extra "Sort" and "Unique" steps.  Guess what those are doing.

"`select distinct`" is *always* a Red Flag for me.
It is almost always used poorly, a band-aid to get around a bigger problem and introduces problems of its own.  Remember, the performance of ...

```
select distinct a, b, c 
. . .
```

... is roughly comparable to that of ...

```
select a, b, c 
. . . 
group by a, b, c 
order by a, b, c
```

Ask yourself why [you think] you need to use "distinct".

Comment: I think it is only fair to point out that sorting is not the only way to implement duplicate removal. Many database engines offer a choice between order-based and hash-based facilities. Hash may be optimal if an explicit sort would be needed, or if there are relatively few output groups. Perhaps address that from a Postgres perspective (if it applies) in your answer?