# Inconsistent results between MySQL and MariaDB when using variables and order

Tags: mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, mariadb-10.2, table-variable

I'm building an accounting table and I need to show the current balance on each transaction.

Everything is working fine in my local environment (Windows 10 + MySQL 5.7.19), but the same query gives me strange results on my VPS (Linux + MariaDB 10.2.31) and in SQL Fiddle (MySQL 5.6).

First the code, then the examples ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b3d75/4)).

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction_types` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `interests` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `hourly` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `salary` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `income` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
INSERT INTO `transaction_types` (`id`, `name`, `slug`, `amount`, `interests`, `hourly`, `salary`, `income`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'Alquiler', 'alquiler', '43000.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 0, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-10 03:26:17'),
(2, 'Campus Nube', 'campus-nube', '13500.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 0, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-10 03:26:33'),
(3, 'Impuestos', 'impuestos', '8400.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 0, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-10 03:26:47'),
(4, 'Marketing', 'marketing', '0.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 0, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-07 09:52:49'),
(5, 'Otros', 'otros', '0.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 0, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-07 09:52:49'),
(6, 'Sueldo', 'sueldo', '750.0000', NULL, 1, 1, 0, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-10 03:28:49'),
(7, 'Videollamadas', 'videollamadas', '0.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 0, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-07 09:52:49'),
(8, 'Cuota', 'cuota', '0.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 1, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-07 09:52:49'),
(9, 'Derecho a examen', 'derecho-a-examen', '0.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 1, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-07 09:52:49'),
(10, 'Materiales', 'materiales', '0.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 1, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-07 09:52:49'),
(11, 'Matrícula', 'matricula', '0.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 1, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-07 09:52:49'),
(12, 'Otros', 'otros-1', '0.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 1, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-07 09:52:49'),
(13, 'Salida didáctica', 'salida-didactica', '0.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 1, '2021-06-07 09:52:49', '2021-06-07 09:52:49'),
(14, 'Sueldo Secretaria', 'sueldo-secretaria', '25780.0000', NULL, 0, 1, 0, '2021-06-10 03:29:21', '2021-06-10 03:29:21'),
(15, 'Gas natural', 'gas-natural', '400.0000', NULL, 0, 0, 0, '2021-06-29 20:40:16', '2021-06-29 20:40:16');

CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `transaction_type_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `payment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `division_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `discount` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `interest` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `total` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `comment` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `transaction_type_id`, `payment_id`, `salary_id`, `division_id`, `user_id`, `amount`, `discount`, `interest`, `total`, `date`, `comment`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(6, 8, NULL, NULL, 96, 81, '3200.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '3200.00', '2021-05-31', 'Cuotas Mayo', '2021-06-10 03:23:38', '2021-06-10 03:23:38'),
(7, 8, NULL, NULL, 96, 80, '3200.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '3200.00', '2021-05-31', 'Cuotas Mayo', '2021-06-10 03:23:38', '2021-06-10 03:23:38'),
(8, 8, NULL, NULL, 96, 96, '3200.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '3200.00', '2021-05-31', 'Cuotas Mayo', '2021-06-10 03:23:38', '2021-06-10 03:23:38'),
(9, 8, NULL, NULL, 96, 120, '3200.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '3200.00', '2021-05-31', 'Cuotas Mayo', '2021-06-10 03:23:38', '2021-06-10 03:23:38'),
(10, 8, NULL, NULL, 96, 31, '3200.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '3200.00', '2021-05-31', 'Cuotas Mayo', '2021-06-10 03:23:38', '2021-06-10 03:23:38'),
(11, 8, NULL, NULL, 96, 25, '3200.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '3200.00', '2021-05-31', 'Cuotas Mayo', '2021-06-10 03:23:38', '2021-06-10 03:23:38'),
(12, 8, NULL, NULL, 96, 35, '3200.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '3200.00', '2021-05-31', 'Cuotas Mayo', '2021-06-10 03:23:38', '2021-06-10 03:23:38'),
(13, 8, NULL, NULL, 96, 46, '3200.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '3200.00', '2021-05-31', 'Cuotas Mayo', '2021-06-10 03:23:38', '2021-06-10 03:23:38'),
(14, 8, NULL, NULL, 96, 202, '3200.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '3200.00', '2021-05-31', 'Cuotas Mayo', '2021-06-10 03:23:38', '2021-06-10 03:23:38'),
(15, 8, NULL, NULL, 96, 40, '3200.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '3200.00', '2021-05-31', 'Cuotas Mayo', '2021-06-10 03:23:38', '2021-06-10 03:23:38'),
(19, 8, NULL, NULL, 95, 111, '5000.0000', '700.0000', '900.0000', '5200.00', '2021-06-06', 'pago cuotas', '2021-06-18 20:50:08', '2021-06-18 20:50:08'),
(20, 8, NULL, NULL, 95, 68, '5000.0000', '700.0000', '900.0000', '5200.00', '2021-06-06', 'pago cuotas', '2021-06-18 20:50:08', '2021-06-18 20:50:08'),
(21, 7, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2000.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '2000.00', '2021-06-04', 'zoom', '2021-06-18 20:50:51', '2021-06-18 20:50:51'),
(36, 14, NULL, 4, NULL, 32, '29780.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '29780.00', '2021-06-05', 'aaa', '2021-06-24 16:44:34', '2021-06-24 16:44:34'),
(37, 6, NULL, 5, NULL, 105, '30000.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '30000.00', '2021-06-01', NULL, '2021-06-24 16:45:25', '2021-06-24 16:45:25'),
(43, 8, 14, NULL, 95, 63, '5000.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '5000.00', '2021-06-01', NULL, '2021-06-24 18:45:19', '2021-06-24 18:45:19'),
(81, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '4000.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '4000.00', '2021-06-02', 'asasas', '2021-06-29 18:43:49', '2021-06-29 18:43:49'),
(83, 6, NULL, 15, NULL, 89, '18250.0000', '0.0000', '0.0000', '18250.00', '2021-06-01', NULL, '2021-06-29 19:04:20', '2021-06-29 19:04:20');
```

Query:

```
SET @balance = 0;
SET @temp = 0;

SELECT SUM(IF(`income`, +`total`, -`total`)) INTO @balance
FROM (
    SELECT `income`, `total`
    FROM `transactions`
    INNER JOIN `transaction_types` ON `transactions`.`transaction_type_id` = `transaction_types`.`id`
    ORDER BY
        `date` desc,
        `transactions`.`created_at` desc,
        `transactions`.`id` asc
    LIMIT 9223372036854775807 OFFSET 0
) AS `sub`;

SELECT
    `transactions`.`id`,
    `transactions`.`date`,
    `transactions`.`total`,
    `transaction_types`.`name` AS `typeName`,
    `transaction_types`.`income`,
    @balance := (@balance - @temp) AS `balance`,
    @temp := IF(`income`, +`total`, -`total`) AS `temp`
FROM `transactions`
INNER JOIN `transaction_types` on `transactions`.`transaction_type_id` = `transaction_types`.`id`
ORDER BY
    `date` desc,
    `transactions`.`created_at` desc,
    `transactions`.`id` asc;
```

This is the expected output (local):

| id | date | income | total | balance | temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 2021-06-06 | 1 | 5200.0000 | -36630.0000 | 5200.0000 |
| 20 | 2021-06-06 | 1 | 5200.0000 | -41830.0000 | 5200.0000 |
| 36 | 2021-06-05 | 0 | 29780.0000 | -47030.0000 | -29780.0000 |
| 21 | 2021-06-04 | 0 | 2000.0000 | -17250.0000 | -2000.0000 |
| 81 | 2021-06-02 | 0 | 4000.0000 | -15250.0000 | -4000.0000 |
| 83 | 2021-06-01 | 0 | 18250.0000 | -11250.0000 | -18250.0000 |
| 43 | 2021-06-01 | 1 | 5000.0000 | 7000.0000 | 5000.0000 |
| 37 | 2021-06-01 | 0 | 30000.0000 | 2000.0000 | -30000.0000 |
| 6 | 2021-05-31 | 1 | 3200.0000 | 32000.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 7 | 2021-05-31 | 1 | 3200.0000 | 28800.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 8 | 2021-05-31 | 1 | 3200.0000 | 25600.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 9 | 2021-05-31 | 1 | 3200.0000 | 22400.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 10 | 2021-05-31 | 1 | 3200.0000 | 19200.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 11 | 2021-05-31 | 1 | 3200.0000 | 16000.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 12 | 2021-05-31 | 1 | 3200.0000 | 12800.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 13 | 2021-05-31 | 1 | 3200.0000 | 9600.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 14 | 2021-05-31 | 1 | 3200.0000 | 6400.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 15 | 2021-05-31 | 1 | 3200.0000 | 3200.0000 | 3200.0000 |

This is what I'm getting (server):

| id | date | total | income | balance | temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | 2021-06-06 | 5200.0000 | 1 | -14380.0000 | 5200.0000 |
| 20 | 2021-06-06 | 5200.0000 | 1 | -19580.0000 | 5200.0000 |
| 36 | 2021-06-05 | 29780.0000 | 0 | -29780.0000 | -29780.0000 |
| 21 | 2021-06-04 | 2000.0000 | 0 | 15620.0000 | -2000.0000 |
| 81 | 2021-06-02 | 4000.0000 | 0 | -36630.0000 | -4000.0000 |
| 83 | 2021-06-01 | 18250.0000 | 0 | -2630.0000 | -18250.0000 |
| 43 | 2021-06-01 | 5000.0000 | 1 | -24780.0000 | 5000.0000 |
| 37 | 2021-06-01 | 30000.0000 | 0 | -32630.0000 | -30000.0000 |
| 6 | 2021-05-31 | 3200.0000 | 1 | 17620.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 7 | 2021-05-31 | 3200.0000 | 1 | 14420.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 8 | 2021-05-31 | 3200.0000 | 1 | 11220.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 9 | 2021-05-31 | 3200.0000 | 1 | 8020.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 10 | 2021-05-31 | 3200.0000 | 1 | 4820.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 11 | 2021-05-31 | 3200.0000 | 1 | 1620.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 12 | 2021-05-31 | 3200.0000 | 1 | -1580.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 13 | 2021-05-31 | 3200.0000 | 1 | -4780.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 14 | 2021-05-31 | 3200.0000 | 1 | -7980.0000 | 3200.0000 |
| 15 | 2021-05-31 | 3200.0000 | 1 | -11180.0000 | 3200.0000 |

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b3d75/4) gives me the same results if I have the `typeName` column on the `SELECT`, if I remove it, the result changes: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b3d75/5). Maybe has something to do with the `JOIN`?

If you read the first table from bottom to top, you will see that the `temp` column (which is the `total` signed) is being added to the `balance`.
-36630.0000 is the total balance, and both tables have that number, but that number should be the first one.

If I delete some records, sometimes the query gives me the expected results, sometimes.

I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: My guess would be it's because of the row processing order. The `order by` clause is applied _after_ the columns in the `select` list are calculated; before that rows are processed in an [undefined order](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228131), so your assumptions about that may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables and Resultset are unordered, so you must give it first an Order in the subquery

> ```
>     SELECT `income`, `total`
>     FROM `transactions`
>     INNER JOIN `transaction_types` ON `transactions`.`transaction_type_id` = `transaction_types`.`id`
>     ORDER BY
>         `date` desc,
>         `transactions`.`created_at` desc,
>         `transactions`.`id` asc
>     LIMIT 9223372036854775807 OFFSET 0
> ```
>
> ```
> income |      total
> -----: | ---------:
>      1 |  5200.0000
>      1 |  5200.0000
>      0 | 29780.0000
>      0 |  2000.0000
>      0 |  4000.0000
>      0 | 18250.0000
>      1 |  5000.0000
>      0 | 30000.0000
>      1 |  3200.0000
>      1 |  3200.0000
>      1 |  3200.0000
>      1 |  3200.0000
>      1 |  3200.0000
>      1 |  3200.0000
>      1 |  3200.0000
>      1 |  3200.0000
>      1 |  3200.0000
>      1 |  3200.0000
> ```

> ```
> SET @balance = 0;
> SET @temp = 0;
>
> SELECT SUM(IF(`income`, +`total`, -`total`)) INTO @balance
> FROM (
>     SELECT `income`, `total`
>     FROM `transactions`
>     INNER JOIN `transaction_types` ON `transactions`.`transaction_type_id` = `transaction_types`.`id`
>     ORDER BY
>         `date` desc,
>         `transactions`.`created_at` desc,
>         `transactions`.`id` asc
>     LIMIT 9223372036854775807 OFFSET 0
> ) AS `sub`;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @balance
> ```
>
> ```
> |    @balance |
> | ----------: |
> | -36630.0000 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @temp
> ```
>
> ```
> | @temp |
> | ----: |
> |     0 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     `id`,
>     `date`,
>     `total`,
>     `name` AS `typeName`,
>     `income`,
>     @balance := (@balance - @temp) AS `balance`,
>     @temp := IF(`income`, +`total`, -`total`) AS `temp`
> FROM
> (SELECT     `transactions`.`id`,
>     `transactions`.`date`,
>     `transactions`.`total`,    `transaction_types`.`name` ,
>     `transaction_types`.`income`
>  FROM `transactions` 
> INNER JOIN `transaction_types` on `transactions`.`transaction_type_id` = `transaction_types`.`id`
>
> ORDER BY
>     `date` desc,
>     `transactions`.`created_at` desc,
>     `transactions`.`id` asc
> LIMIT 9223372036854775807 OFFSET 0) t3;
> ```

> ```
> id | date       |      total | typeName          | income |     balance |        temp
> -: | :--------- | ---------: | :---------------- | -----: | ----------: | ----------:
> 19 | 2021-06-06 |  5200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 | -36630.0000 |   5200.0000
> 20 | 2021-06-06 |  5200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 | -41830.0000 |   5200.0000
> 36 | 2021-06-05 | 29780.0000 | Sueldo Secretaria |      0 | -47030.0000 | -29780.0000
> 21 | 2021-06-04 |  2000.0000 | Videollamadas     |      0 | -17250.0000 |  -2000.0000
> 81 | 2021-06-02 |  4000.0000 | Marketing         |      0 | -15250.0000 |  -4000.0000
> 83 | 2021-06-01 | 18250.0000 | Sueldo            |      0 | -11250.0000 | -18250.0000
> 43 | 2021-06-01 |  5000.0000 | Cuota             |      1 |   7000.0000 |   5000.0000
> 37 | 2021-06-01 | 30000.0000 | Sueldo            |      0 |   2000.0000 | -30000.0000
>  6 | 2021-05-31 |  3200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 |  32000.0000 |   3200.0000
>  7 | 2021-05-31 |  3200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 |  28800.0000 |   3200.0000
>  8 | 2021-05-31 |  3200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 |  25600.0000 |   3200.0000
>  9 | 2021-05-31 |  3200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 |  22400.0000 |   3200.0000
> 10 | 2021-05-31 |  3200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 |  19200.0000 |   3200.0000
> 11 | 2021-05-31 |  3200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 |  16000.0000 |   3200.0000
> 12 | 2021-05-31 |  3200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 |  12800.0000 |   3200.0000
> 13 | 2021-05-31 |  3200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 |   9600.0000 |   3200.0000
> 14 | 2021-05-31 |  3200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 |   6400.0000 |   3200.0000
> 15 | 2021-05-31 |  3200.0000 | Cuota             |      1 |   3200.0000 |   3200.0000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7553fecbbab422a3ff32e05d9d644efd)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just two questions: 1. If I need to paginate the results, it's OK to do it outside the subquery? `LIMIT 9223372036854775807 OFFSET 0) t3 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;`. It's the simplest way to make it work with the pagination system of Laravel. 2. Why I don't need to do this subquery in my local environment? Thanks again.

Comment: That depends on the version you got, later updates as in the fiddle implemented that "feature". it was anoying, as i had to rewrite my queiries new, it is now mor estandard compatible

Comment: Don't want to be annoying, but what about the pagination? It makes a difference if I `LIMIT` the subquery to?

Comment: That is no problem , the high number guarantees that you get all rows even high bigibt numbers , Burt as you can use where clauses you can also use limit and offset, you have to be carefull that you got all